# In a Prüfer 2-group every subgroup is marginal.

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G$ be the multiplicative group of all complex $2^n$th roots of unity, $n=0,1,2,...$. Prove that every subgroup of $G$ is marginal.

$G$ is the Prüfer $2$-group. I happen to know that every proper subgroup of a Prüfer $p$-group is finite and cyclic. Let's  try with $H=\langle 1/2+Z\rangle$. I must find $W$ such that $H$ is a $W$-marginal subgroup. Let $g_1-h_1\in H$. Then $g_1$ and $h_1$ are in the same coset of $H$, say the coset $n/2^r+Z+H$ and $g_1=n/2^r+s/2+Z$, $h_1=n/2^r+t/2+Z$ for some $s,t\in Z$. That is $g_1=(n+2^{r-1}s)/2^r+Z$, $h_1=(n+2^{r-1}t)/2^r+Z$. Then if I put $w=2^rx_1$ I have $2^rg_1=2^rh_1$, that is $w(g_1)=w(h_1)$ and $H$ is $W$-marginal. Is this proof valid? (In the same way we can prove that $H=\langle 1/2^u+Z)$ is $W$-marginal for some $W$.)

Comment: You are using a mixture of additive and multiplicative notation, which makes it very hard to read. But the main problem is that you have not said what $r$ is. In additive notation, I think you want $w = 2^rx_1$ for the subgroup $\langle 1/2^r + {\mathbb Z} \rangle$.

Comment: I don't understand your objection. If $g_1-h_1\in H$ then there is an element $\bar g$ in $G$ such that both $g_1$ and $h_1$ belong to $\bar g+H$, say $\bar g=n/2^r+Z$. Isn't that clear?

Comment: No, it is not clear. You are trying to find a word $w$ with respect to which the subgroup $H = \langle 1/2 + {\mathbb Z} \rangle$ is marginal, and your answer involved a number $r$, which you have not defined. The answer has to be a single specific word.

Comment: I've got it! $W={x_1^2}$. Reading the question it is easily verified.